# Windows 10 & Remote Desktop: how to open ports?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, firewall

I have a windows 10 pc connected to the internet via a Netgear N300 modem. I managed to easily find the firewall setting on my modem to open port 3389 for remote desktop, but I can find no way to make it work. I added 2 port rules (tcp&udp) for 3389 in advanced security options on my windows firewall, I also added rules for no-ip's duc and remote desktop's program, but if I check with online port checker 3389 is always closed. What can I do?
I already set static ip to my pc and also port forwarding to it

Comment: It's becoming increasingly common for ISPs to put you behind what is called carrier-grade (or large scale) network translation. You can try asking your provider if this is the case for you. If it is, getting a static IP is the way to go. Some VPN services will also allow you to forward ports while you are connected, which might be enough for your situation.

Comment: I do not have static IP, but i used no-ip dynamic DNS to link a host to my machine

Comment: @Kodeeo NO-IP does nothing to the USP situation commented above.

Comment: @Kodeo The point is that static IPs are dedicated to you, which automatically means that you are not part of a CGN. Also this communicates to your ISP that you need to be able to open ports and accept connections.